# sending email through exchange server via zend server

Tags: zend-framework, email, zend-form, zend-studio

I want to send a local e-mail through exchange server
but zend give me this Message

> "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond."

this is my code

```
$mailTransport = 
   new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtpserver.edu.com', array(
            'auth'     => 'login',
            'username' => 'dummy.edu.com',
            'password' => '123456',
            'port'     => '25',
        ));           

        Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($mailTransport);

        $mail = new Zend_Mail();
        $mail->setFrom('dummy.edu.com');//anas.azmeh@ucti.edu.my');
        $mail->setBodyHtml('some message - it may be html formatted text');
        $mail->addTo('dummy.edu.com', 'recipient');
        $mail->setSubject('subject');
        $mail->send();
```

I tried the same code in gmail configuration and it works perfectly
please help me as fast as possible

Comment: from the error msg it seems problem is with smtpserver.edu.com not in your code if that's correct address.

Answer (score 1):

```
$mail = new Mail\Message();
$mail->setBody("Send Mail");
$mail->setFrom('test@gmail.com', 'Test Site');
$mail->addTo($email_id, 'Test Site');
$mail->setSubject('Your connection is not stablish');

$transport = new Mail\Transport\Sendmail();
$transport->send($mail);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that port 25, 23 and 587 are blocked
because I tried to telnet them but it give me fail, so the problem may come from these blocking